# make image blur effect with Intervention library in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

i'm trying to add blur effect on my image. I'm using laravel 5.2 and [Intervention Image 2 library](https://github.com/Intervention/image). here's [blur method](http://image.intervention.io/api/blur) . I did exactly the same in my code but it doesn't do anything(image stays the same). here's code:
in my controller where I store input data and image also, I call `makeBlur()`helper function. image path stores in `$path_preview`

controller :

```
// some code ...
makeBlur($path_preview); // <-- looks like /uplodas/image.jpg
// some code ....
$model->path_preview = $path_preview;
$model->save();
```

here's helper function:

```
// $image is string (stores the path of file)
function makeBlur($image){
  $path = public_path() . $image; // get image path add public/ in front of it
  $blurredImg = \Image::make($path);
  $blurredImg->blur(45);
}
```

no errors, just nothing happens. maybe i didn't get the idea how it works

Comment: and where did you save the blurred image?

Comment: thank you! I thought it was void method which only change the file. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the image after you applied the blur

```
$blurredImg->blur(45)->save($image);
```